# What is a better way to do a console with DHTML?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'd like to find a better way to output console messages to an HTML page.  This method seems to be pretty slow.

```
<html>
<title>Logging test</title>
<head>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript" TYPE="text/javascript">
<!--

function log(s) {
    if(!log.start) {
        var date = new Date();
        log.count = 0;
        _log("0", "log() started at " + date);
        log.start = date.valueOf();
    }
    _log(new Date().valueOf() - log.start, s);
}

function _log(header, s) {
    var logMessages = document.getElementById("logMessages");
    if(!logMessages) {
        alert(logMessages);
        return;
    }
    var message = document.createElement("div");
    message.className = "logMessage";
    var content = "";
    content += "<span class=\"time\">" + header + "</span>";
    content += "<span class=\"line\">" + (log.count++) + "</span>";
    content += "<span class=\"level\">" + "" + "</span>";
    content += "<span class=\"msg\">" + s.replace(/ /g, "&nbsp;").replace(/\n/g, "<BR />") + "</span>";
    message.innerHTML = content;
    logMessages.appendChild(message);
    setTimeout(function(){message.scrollIntoView(true)},1);
}

function main(e) {
    if(window.confirm("Would you like to display logging?")) {
        for(var i=0;i<5000;i++) {
            log("Hello World " + i);
        }
    }
}
//-->
</SCRIPT>

<style>
.logMessage {
    border-bottom: 1px black solid;
    font-size: 8pt;
    font-family: Lucida Console;
}

.logMessage .line, .logMessage .time {
    width: 30px;
}

.logMessage .level {
    display: none;
}

.logMessage .msg {
}

#logMessages {
    overflow: auto;
}
</style>

</head>
<body onload="main()">
<div id="logMessages"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Speed seems fine to me, though the scroll might be causing some issues with lots of logs happening quickly.  Only issue I see is that in FF the rendering of log messages dies after about 2300 (just shows blank after that), though IE and chrome render it fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's the use case here? For debugging, Firebug's [console.log](http://getfirebug.com/console.html) is all I can ever imagine needing. For your specific case, if you really want it to go to on the page and find your current solution to be too slow, I would definitely replace all the string concatenations with something a little more efficient (pushing strings into an array and joining them at the end, or a StringBuffer that abstracts it out), as string manipulation in Javascript is [infamously bad](http://ajaxian.com/archives/string-performance-in-ie-arrayjoin-vs-continued) in [some browsers](http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2008/05/09/string-performance-an-analysis/) (I'm looking at you, Redmond!)

Comment: Out of curiosity I modified his code to use the array method.  10x faster! (original code took 11 seconds in Chrome.  array method took slightly less than 2 seconds).

Comment: Yup. Makes a world of difference.

Answer (score 3):

Firebug is nice is you're using Firefox to test your work (assuming you want to log messages for debugging purposes). If you're testing other browsers, you can also use [Firebug Lite](http://getfirebug.com/lite.html) which mimics the functionality of Firebug in other browsers. That way you don't have to re-invent the wheel.